# Struts2 RoleInterceptor example

Tags: struts2

Could you please post a code example to implement roles interceptor ? On the documentation it just says: will only be executed if the user has the correct role. (http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/roles-interceptor.html).

Besides than than check if user is logined, I want to check if he has the role to execute the action.

Thanks in advance,
Raju

Comment: You don't need to implement this interceptor. Just configure it in `struts.xml` file.

Comment: Can i get some sample code?

Comment: Sure. Just go to the correct page in the documentation: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/roles-interceptor.html